# cannot convert from 'UnityEngine.WWWForm' to 'string

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public class SubmitEmailListBuilding : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public WWWForm form;

    public Text emailText;
    
    void Start () 
    {
    }
    
    
    void Update () 
    {
    }


    public IEnumerator SendToMailChimp()
    {
        form = new WWWForm ();
        form.AddField ("MERGE0", "DEMO@gmail.com");
        form.AddField ("MERGE1", "Delta");
        form.AddField ("MERGE2", "Tribe");

        form.AddField ("u", "00c0d014c9ccceb88dae783");
        form.AddField ("id", "3444d462a2f");


        // IT WAS LIKE THIS 
        //WWW w = new WWW ("https://demo.us5.list-manage.com/subscribe/post", form);
        // BUT WWW IS ABSOLUTE IN UNITY AND WHEN I CHANGED IT TO UnityWebRequest I FACED THIS ERROR
        UnityWebRequest w = new UnityWebRequest("https://demo.us5.list-manage.com/subscribe/post", form);
        
        yield return w;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty (w.error)) 
        {
            print ("we have an error");
        } 
        else 
        {
            print ("form submitted successfully");
        }
    }

    public void PressedSendToMailChimpButton()
    {
        StartCoroutine (SendToMailChimp ());
    }
}
```

Comment: I think by `ABSOLUTE` you rather meant `OBSOLETE` ;)

Answer (score 0):

The constrictor of [`UnityWebRequest`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest-ctor.html) indeed only takes as arguments

```
public UnityWebRequest();
public UnityWebRequest(string url);
public UnityWebRequest(Uri uri);
public UnityWebRequest(string url, string method);
public UnityWebRequest(Uri uri, string method);
public UnityWebRequest(string url, string method, Networking.DownloadHandler downloadHandler, Networking.UploadHandler uploadHandler);
public UnityWebRequest(Uri uri, string method, Networking.DownloadHandler downloadHandler, Networking.UploadHandler uploadHandler);
```

you don't want to use this constructor anyway, because otherwise you would have to completely compose your request from scratch including at minimum the [`method`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest-method.html), [`uploadHandler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest-uploadHandler.html) and [`downloadHandler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest-downloadHandler.html) etc.

What you rather want to do is using a [`UnityWebRequest.Post`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Post.html)

```
public static Networking.UnityWebRequest Post(string uri, WWWForm formData);
```

> Create a `UnityWebRequest` configured to send form data to a server via HTTP POST.
>
> This method creates a `UnityWebRequest`, sets the `url` to the string uri argument and sets the `method` to `POST`. The Content-Type header will be copied from the formData parameter.
>
> This method attaches a `DownloadHandlerBuffer` to the `UnityWebRequest`. This is for convenience, as we anticipate most users will use the `DownloadHandler` to check replies from the server, particularly in the case of REST APIs.

---

Then also instead of

```
yield return w;
```

it should then rather be

```
yield return w.SendWebRequest();
```